# Callback in multi instance k8s

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, microservices

I have a microsevice app (A) run in multi instance in K8S, when have a request (1) from client via Load balance, it will send another request (2) to other app (B) to execute a long task,
(2) will return ACK immediate if is push request to (B) success ,
(1) will wait until B execute finish.
After B process finish, B callback A via other api via load balance

```
Client      microservice A        microservice B
  |       (1)      |                    |
  |--------------->| push request (2)   |
  |                |------------------->|
  |                | ack request (3)    |
  |                |<-------------------|
  |                |                    |
  |                | A waiting callback |
  |                | from B             |
  |                |--                  |
  |                |  |                 |
  |                |  |                 |
  |                |<-                  |
  |                |  B callback A      |
  | A return client|<-------------------|
  |<---------------|                    |
  |                |                    |
  |                |                    |
```

My application provide a callback method to B and B will call this when B finish execute task via a load balance.

Problem here is because application run in multi instance, the callback may go into different node/pod with first sender node/pod .

Is there anyway to A pod process the callback of request it push to B

Comment: I'd recommend keeping the state somewhere outside the container, maybe in a side Redis or PostgreSQL container depending on the size of the state required.  Then the callback can recover the state from the data store, even if it's not the same container.  Note that the original requesting container isn't guaranteed to still exist, pods get deleted from Kubernetes somewhat routinely and not necessarily under your control.

Comment: yes, the original request container may not exist , this time it will return a error to caller so I don't care about this case, just in normal case original request container still wait for callback from other app (B) when B finish execute task

Comment: You can try to utilise `session affinity` on services - "If you want to make sure that connections from a particular client are passed to the same Pod each time, you can select the session affinity based on the client's IP addresses by setting service.spec.sessionAffinity to "ClientIP" (the default is "None").", see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#configuration) for more details.